# Fetch text UIColor in XCUITest

Tags: uibutton, uilabel, xctest, uicolor, xcuitest

I am writing UI tests from my watchOS project and currently looking how to fetch `UIColor` attribute from from `UILabel` and `UIButton` in XCUIText?
Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCUITest is color-blind. You can either use a snapshot comparison tool or in your application store the color in the accessibility identifier and update it as it changes.